# How to call DataAnnotations in business layer (ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, validation, data-annotations, business-logic, dto

I would like to use the DataAnnotations on my transfer objects. However how do I call them in the business layer to verify the input?

Is this by some method call or reflection?

I do not use ASP.NET but standard ASP.NET and would like to call the data annotations in the business layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Validator class in the following link.  It has a variety of methods which essentially give you a boolean letting you know if something is valid and the associated error messages.

.net 4 and silverlight only though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382181.aspx